# How do I get my windows host machine browser to connect to my Apache Mesos vagrant virtualbox?

Tags: apache, windows-7, vagrant, virtualbox, mesos

I have been trying to follow a tutorial for building an Apache Mesos cluster on my home machine.  I am able to get everything to work fine at work, but seem to be having some Vagrant/VirtualBox issues here at home.
I get to exercise 3 of the tutorial [Tutorial](https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/using-apache-mesos/) and I try "192.168.33.10:5050" in my browser and I cannot connect.
Below are the settings of my vagrant file:

```
 Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
 config.vm.hostname = "node1"
 end
```

Below is a copy of my /etc/hosts:

```
 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4      localhost4.localdomain4
 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6      localhost6.localdomain6
 192.168.33.10 node1
```

When I add another node to the cluster I can ping the nodes between one another, but I cannot ping either from the host.
Below is the result of running netstat.  Results match what the tutorial says that I should be seeing:

```
 [vagrant@node1 ~]$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep mesos                       
 tcp        
 0      0 0.0.0.0:5050            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
 948/mesos-master     
 tcp        
 0      0 0.0.0.0:5051            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
 949/mesos-slave
```

I have tried port forwarding, but vagrant will not allow the settings to be saved and it will just switch them back to the original settings each time.
I am using a Windows 7 host, the newest version of Vagrant and of Virtualbox.  I have tried downgrading both and reinstalling, none of which works.
How do I get my host machine browser connect to my Apache Mesos vagrant virtualbox?

Comment: The hostname need to be in your windows host file... Or use https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager

Comment: Are you talking about the vagrantfile?  If not, where do i find the windows host file and how do I add the hostname?